# Ubuntu 19.04 and HDMI sound problem

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, 19.04

Right after Ubuntu 19.04 was release, I tried it (Ubuntu MATE 19.04 Final release to be precisely) from live CD and found it cannot output sound to my TV via HDMI.

- the videos are shown on TV, but
- the sound are still coming from my laptop
- when viewing the sound devices, only built-in sound device are found/listed, no HDMI sound device found/listed.
- then I found it is not only live CD's problem, because I did a fresh installation as well, and the symptom is the same.

Note that previous iterations of Ubuntu MATE worked well, and if I switch back to 18.04, then everything is fine again.

How can I fix the problem?

PS.

I [reported the problem to the ubuntu-mate community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-19-04-final-release-and-hdmi/19443) more than a month ago, but no reply yet.

PPS.

Here is my sound card info (viewing from 18.04):

```
$ lspci | grep Graphics
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e10000 irq 29

$ aplay -l 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC270 Analog [ALC270 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Which graphics card?

Comment: Updated in OP - VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)